# Given a char array buffer of length n delete m characters from position pos

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memcpy

**I want to delete characters from a unsigned char buffer**

C language:

```
unsigned char buff[n] = "...."; // len n byte array
```

I thought of using memmove

```
memmove(buff + pos, buff + pos + m, ???);
```

Can anyone help with what should the value of ??? be, I am getting the correct result of m characters deleted irrespective of ??? value (any value between n - pos to n)

Values of m and pos are less than n and the buff is a byte array (A data packet)

Comment: How many characters should be copied?

Comment: did you know that with memcpy, the source and destination areas aren't allowed to overlap? (If they can overlap use memmove)

Comment: If I use memmove what value should I use in ???

Comment: Are you dealing with a byte array or a string?  How many apposite assertions can you make about the values of `n`, `m`, and `pos` can you make?

Comment: Get yourself a piece of paper and a pencil, and make a nice drawing.

Comment: @Rishab V Arun It is unclear whether the buffer contains a string or not.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It is a unsigned char (or byte) buffer

Comment: @RishabVArun You need to figure out what you want it to move. Pen and paper helps, like wildplasser suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this code is not optimized at all but shows what i think is the easiest to understand method:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void delete(int p, const char * str){
    char *done;
    int t = strlen(str); 
    if(p>t||p<=0){
        return; 
    }else{
        strcpy(done, str);
        strcpy(done+p-1,str+p); 
    }
    strcpy(str, done);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buff[] = "abcdefghi"; 
    delete(3, buff); 
    printf(buff);//it prints abcdefghi
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is simple strcpy takes two parameters the first being a pointer to the destination string(`str`) and the second a pointer to origin.

we start by copying the whole original string(`str`) to our temporary string(`done`)

Then we just copy `str+p` ( p being the position on the string starting at 1 and ending at strlen, since strlen excludes the terminator byte we check till the last position) to `done+p-1` as we want to erase/overlap the char at the position p

Finally we just copy `done`, to the original string(`str`) and we have successfully erased a character

---

Also since we are using strcpy, the function takes care of the terminator byte, we also don't have to pay much attention to freeing the temporary pointer although the compiler will complain about the casting of the origin string's which are fairly simple to resolve but to keep it easy to figure out the logic I've kept out of the answer

Comment: Also forgot to add this is just a scratch, memory functions namely, memmove, memcpy, etc... can be tricky to deal with and if you aren't absolutely certain of what you want it to do, putting it in practice will result in a disaster since you have to not only keep in mind technical details but also the "algorithm" itself. So i figured that after understanding in depth the answer above, doing it with memcpy or memmove should be a breeze